# Looping through R data-frame is not behaving as expected. Why?

Tags: r

My goal is to loop through an R dataframe row by row. I know that you can do it outside of a loop by indexing, like if I want rows 1 to 5 of my dataframe df, I just do df[1:5,], and that gives me rows 1:5 for every column in my dataframe. But often I don't know exactly which rows I want, but I want to loop through my dataframe row by row within a for loop, so that I can apply "if" conditionals, and reading the rows into a list, and grepping for matches. I haven't figured out every step of my problem, but I'm wondering just why this for loop isn't behaving as I expect it would and I wish it would.

So I'm working with the built-in R dataset "CO2". 
So it looks like this with 84 rows and 5 columns:

```
> CO2[1:10,]
   Plant   Type  Treatment conc uptake
1    Qn1 Quebec nonchilled   95   16.0
2    Qn1 Quebec nonchilled  175   30.4
3    Qn1 Quebec nonchilled  250   34.8
4    Qn1 Quebec nonchilled  350   37.2
5    Qn1 Quebec nonchilled  500   35.3
6    Qn1 Quebec nonchilled  675   39.2
7    Qn1 Quebec nonchilled 1000   39.7
8    Qn2 Quebec nonchilled   95   13.6
9    Qn2 Quebec nonchilled  175   27.3
10   Qn2 Quebec nonchilled  250   37.1
```

This is what I've achieved so far.

```
   for(i in 1:nrow(CO2)) # "i" is incrementer from 1 to 84.
    {
        r <- CO2[i,] # r is our current row. 
        if(r$conc == 95 & r$Treatment == "nonchilled"){print(r)} 

    }
```

So this is what I get from that code.

```
 Plant   Type  Treatment conc uptake
1   Qn1 Quebec nonchilled   95     16
  Plant   Type  Treatment conc uptake
8   Qn2 Quebec nonchilled   95   13.6
   Plant   Type  Treatment conc uptake
15   Qn3 Quebec nonchilled   95   16.2
   Plant        Type  Treatment conc uptake
43   Mn1 Mississippi nonchilled   95   10.6
   Plant        Type  Treatment conc uptake
50   Mn2 Mississippi nonchilled   95     12
   Plant        Type  Treatment conc uptake
57   Mn3 Mississippi nonchilled   95   11.3
```

That's pretty cool. However, I wasn't expecting it to duplicate the headers, so how can I modify my code to produce this result in the for loop without using the subset function? So I want the output to look like this:

```
 Plant        Type  Treatment conc uptake
1    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled   95   16.0
8    Qn2      Quebec nonchilled   95   13.6
15   Qn3      Quebec nonchilled   95   16.2
43   Mn1 Mississippi nonchilled   95   10.6
50   Mn2 Mississippi nonchilled   95   12.0
57   Mn3 Mississippi nonchilled   95   11.3
```

As you can see the headers only occur once. Yes, the subset function is powerful, but it kind of disconnects me from iterating over my dataframe row by row.

In addition, I find it interesting that my for loop gives me the row numbers in which the concentration is both 95 and the Treatment is "nonchilled" at the same time. So how could I isolate those in my for loop?

Hey, I figured something out. I realized that R was interpreting variable "r" as a data-frame with all columns and 1 row. So if insider the if conditional, I remove the column names from "r" there, I get this result that looks pretty nice, with row numbers, but unfortunately no headers.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(CO2)) # "i" is incrementer from 1 to 84.
{
    r <- CO2[i,] # r is our current row. 
    if(r$conc == 95 & r$Treatment == "nonchilled"){
        names(r) = NULL; # Removes headers. # It's important to do it here specifically.
        print(r)} 
}
```

So it produces this:

```
 1 Qn1 Quebec nonchilled 95 16

8 Qn2 Quebec nonchilled 95 13.6

15 Qn3 Quebec nonchilled 95 16.2

43 Mn1 Mississippi nonchilled 95 10.6

50 Mn2 Mississippi nonchilled 95 12

57 Mn3 Mississippi nonchilled 95 11.3
```

Comment: You are using `print`.  Do you really need a `for` loop?

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out alternative ways of solving a problem, processing a data-frame more classically like you would in other languages. This is a basic example so I was hoping to learn things from it, so that I can apply it to higher level problems in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you:

```
df<-data.frame(Plant=character(0), Type=character(0), 
                Treatment=character(0), conc=numeric(0), 
                uptake=numeric(0))

for(i in 1:nrow(CO2)){if(CO2$conc[i]==95 & CO2$Treatment[i]=="nonchilled"){
df<-rbind(df,CO2[i,])}}
> df
#    Plant        Type  Treatment conc uptake
#1    Qn1      Quebec nonchilled   95   16.0
#8    Qn2      Quebec nonchilled   95   13.6
#15   Qn3      Quebec nonchilled   95   16.2
#43   Mn1 Mississippi nonchilled   95   10.6
#50   Mn2 Mississippi nonchilled   95   12.0
#57   Mn3 Mississippi nonchilled   95   11.3
```

Comment: @xyz123 what's funny? isn't this what you were looking for?

Comment: Well, I specifically asked for alternative ways to solve the problem without using the subset function, and I know how to do that exactly with the subset function.

Comment: Yes, it's beautiful. Thank you!

Comment: Done. Congratulations! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working code. But the headers are misaligned.

```
df <- mtcars
print(paste(colnames(df)))
for (i in seq(1,10)){
    r <- paste(df[i,])  
  print(r)
}
```

However, I am not sure if this is very helpful for your ultimate goal. You may try to post a new question with ultimate intent. Generally, R has alternative, better option for almost anything that is accomplished by a loop.

Comment: Thank you. R does have many ways of solving a problem without a classical for loop which almost makes it seem like R cannot efficiently use for-loops in R because not many R users ever use for-loops, using R-base wrapper functions instead usually. So I think it's a shame that R code with for-loops and while loops is nearly impossible to find, even though R can do these.

Comment: I don't think it's a shame!! I believe even you will start using other options soon because 1) they are faster 2) they are much more readable and concise to write. Anyways, did my solution provided you an answer?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't do exactly what I thought it would do.
It produces an output like this, and does not include row numbers,
and I'm not sure what [1] and [7] means here. 

 [1] "21"    "6"     "160"   "110"   "3.9"   "2.62" 

 [7] "16.46" "0"     "1"     "4"     "4"    

 [1] "21"    "6"     "160"   "110"   "3.9"   "2.875"

 [7] "17.02" "0"     "1"     "4"     "4"    

 [1] "22.8"  "4"     "108"   "93"    "3.85"  "2.32" 

 [7] "18.61" "1"     "1"     "4"     "1"

Comment: Even though you were not able to get the row numbers, I'm impressed that you did not duplicate the headers like me. That's good.